# Velocity Templates - New Line

Tags: java, templates, velocity

I've been working with Apache's Velocity engine and a custom template.
The thing is, that I haven't been able to generate a String with the corresponding line breaks.
I tried almost everything that I found, such as using $esc.n and $esc.newline (I'm already using escape tools on my project) but  it seems that the version I'm currently using doesn't support it (1.4), checked if putting '\n', '\\n' and even '\\\n' would work, but same thing.

Does anyone have any solution to this?

Comment: I have always just put newlines in the template itself and the output has newlines in the same place.  Can you give an example?

Comment: The Velocity devs have always worked hard to keep backward compatibility.  Please consider upgrading from 1.4, that version is ancient and literally hundreds of things (if not thousands) have been fixed and improved since then.  :)

Comment: Yes, I suggested the upgrade to the latest version, but it's not up to me :(.  
Peter, I think that behaviour is part of the latest Velocity versions. :(

Answer (score 22, accepted):

We had issues with newlines and ended up putting a property on the VelocityContext:

```
VelocityContext ctx = new VelocityContext();
ctx.put("newline", "\n");
```

Then, wherever we needed to use a newline, we would reference the context variable:

```
$newline
```

We use this in cases where we need to replace newlines in a string with <br />.

Comment: I'll try with the context solution. Will provide an update on the results. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for your help :). For anyone wondering, I simply added that property to the context, and referenced it in the template just like you instructed.

Comment: Hi I am using this to get the body of the email: 
String body = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(
                    velocityEngine, filename, params);
in params I have param.put("newline", "\n") and in velocity template (the .vm file) I am using it like this $newline but doesn't seem to work, any ideas?

Comment: @TouseefZafar Unfortunately, it has been several years since I have used Velocity, so I am probably not of much help now. The one thing that stands out to me is (presumably) your "params" object is a Map. Is that equivalent to the Velocity Context? If not, this solution may not work.

Answer (score 9):

I needed a new line for generating javascript. Well, I didn't *need* it of course, but it made reading the generated code easier while developing. In this case, I just set a variable so that the Velocity was easier to read. This is all you need:

### Velocity Code:

```
#set( $newline="
")
#set( $jsCode = "var bling='blang';{$newline}var bark='bite';{$newline}" )
<script>
$jsCode</script>
```

### Result:

```
<script>
var bling='blang';
var bark='bite';
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Are you using Velocity to generate HTML content? In that case remember that you need to use `<br>` not a newline.

If you actually want a new line character you just put the actual new line character, i.e. press enter. There is no escape sequences like \n in Velocity.

Comment: I'm using Velocity to generate XML content. Also, that feature about using enter to add a new line, is a behaviour of latest versions.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Velocity 1.5 or later, you can also just put the new line in there:

```
#set( $foo = "this has a 
line break" )
```

Answer (score 2):

In Velocity 1.4 neither newlines in strings works nor does the `escapeTool.getNewline()` exist. If you do not have the possibility to add anything to the context, here is a Velocity-only hack to generate arbitrary characters:

```
#macro(chr $charCode $str)
  #set($str="0")
  #set($chars=$str.charAt(0).toChars($charCode))
  #set($str="")
  #foreach($char in $chars)
    #set($str="$str$char")
  #end
#end

#chr(10 $nl)

First Line${nl}Second Line
```

It uses [Character.toChars()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toChars(int)) to convert the ASCII code `0x0A = 10` to a `char[]` which it then assembles into a string. This way one could generate any character such as

```
#chr(129299 $nerd) ## U+1F913 => 0x1F913 = 129299
$nerd
## outputs
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be easiest to simply use the Velocity EscapeTool.

See this link: https://velocity.apache.org/tools/releases/2.0/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/EscapeTool.html#getNewline%28%29

Example Usage:
Line Break Here: $esc.newline This is on a new line.

Comment: I am facing a similar problem.. I have a form where i enter comment text and send an email.. however if the use has pressed enter(newline) that does not appear in the email.. comment text appears in a single line

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing in my two cents here, here is what I came up with:

```
#set( $E = "" )
#set ( $System = $E.class.forName('java.lang.System'))
#set( $NL = $System.lineSeparator() )
```

when used, `$NL` produces a line break.

Also note, if you are in a loop, you might don't need that hassle at all. for example:

```
#set( $s = "abc" )
#foreach( $e in $s.split("") )
$e
#end
```

will already produce

```
a
b
c
```