# Spring email and new line character

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, velocity

Can someone tell me how to insert newline characters in email content. I use this code snippet to send emails.

```
public boolean sendMail(final Account player, final Object tl, final String type)
{
    MimeMessagePreparator preparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {
        public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception
        {
            MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage);

            String msgAdmin = msgFrom;
            message.setTo(player.getEmail()); // TODO: changed from msgAdmin to player.getEmail()
            message.setFrom(msgFrom);
            message.setSubject(type + " invitation");
            Map model = new HashMap();
            model.put("tl", tl);
            model.put("player", player);
            model.put("type", type);
            String text = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine,
                    "com/test/mail/invite.vm", model);
            logger.debug(text);
            message.setText(text, true);
        }
    };
    return sendMail(preparator);
}
```

I tried \r\n characters in the email content. But it doesn't seem to work. HTML markup like BR tag works, but i dont want to add html markups in the email content. Any other solution is possible?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549427/velocity-templates-new-line

Answer (score 2):

Actually the problem is when you are invoking the message.setText, you are setting the second arguement to true.  Which means the message is interpreted as HTML.  In order for the emails newlines to show, just set that second argument to false.

Answer (score 1):

Newline characters and velocity templates is a well-documented problem. The best workaround is to stash "\n" as a value of a property that you make available to template. Then reference that property.

Comment: Break this problem into pieces. Print out text of your message before sending. Is there a newline? Some mail clients (outlook is one) will strip out certain newlines. Sometimes you need to double-up newlines to make it treat it like a paragraph break.